# Pandas Groupby : group **by** a column containing tuples

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to group **by** a column containing tuples. Each tuple has a different length.

I'd like to perform simple groupby operations on this column of tuples, such as sum or count.

Example :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
                    'col1': [1,2,3,4]  ,
                    'col2': [('a', 'b'), ('a'), ('b', 'n', 'k'), ('a', 'c', 'k', 'z') ] ,
                    })

print df
```

outputs :

```
   col1          col2
0     1        (a, b)
1     2        (a, m)
2     3     (b, n, k)
3     4  (a, c, k, z)
```

I'd like to be able to group **by** col2 **on** col1, with for instance a sum.

Expected output would be :

```
   col2        sum_col1
0     a        7
1     b        4
2     c        4
3     n        3
3     m        2
3     k        7
3     z        4
```

I feel that pd.melt might be able to use, but i can't see exactly how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach using `.get_dummies` and `.melt`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
                    'col1': [1,2,3,4]  ,
                    'col2': [('a', 'b'), ('a'), ('b', 'n', 'k'), ('a', 'c', 'k', 'z') ] ,
                    })

value_col = 'col1'
id_col = 'col2'
```

Unpack tuples to DataFrame:

```
df = df.join(df.col2.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x)))
```

Create columns with values of tuples:

```
dummy_cols = df.columns.difference(df[[value_col, id_col]].columns)
dfd = pd.get_dummies(df[dummy_cols | pd.Index([value_col])])
```

Producing:

```
   col1  0_a  0_b  1_b  1_c  1_n  2_k  3_z
0     1    1    0    1    0    0    0    0
1     2    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
2     3    0    1    0    0    1    1    0
3     4    1    0    0    1    0    1    1
```

Then `.melt` it and clean `variable` column from prefixes:

```
dfd = pd.melt(dfd, value_vars=dfd.columns.difference([value_col]).tolist(), id_vars=value_col)
dfd['variable'] = dfd.variable.str.replace(r'\d_', '')
print dfd.head()
```

Yielding:

```
   col1 variable  value
0     1        a      1
1     2        a      1
2     3        a      0
3     4        a      1
4     1        b      0
```

And finally get your output:

```
dfd[dfd.value != 0].groupby('variable')[value_col].sum()

    variable
a           7
b           4
c           4
k           7
n           3
z           4
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks Primer ! I've learned quite a few new tricks here ! Question : can ` df.columns.difference(df[[value_col, id_col]].columns)` be simplified into ` df.columns.difference([value_col, id_col])` or is there a reason for that more complex form ?

Comment: `df.columns.difference([value_col, id_col])` is also ok in this case. `.difference` is a method of `Index` object and fail safe approach would be to use it with another `Index` object. But it seems it can work with lists too.

Comment: @Primer - Hey Primer, this is exactly what I'm looking for. But your steps are pretty advanced and confusing for pandas noobs like me. Would you care to elaborate/annotate further? Would really appreciate it!

Comment: @SpicyClubSauce - If you can be more specific about what would you like to be clarified I think it can be done. I would however recommend first to run the code line by line (separating unclear bits) and see what it does. Here are links to the docs of [`.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) and [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html)